# A way to get just directories and PIDs using wmic?

Tags: ruby, weblogic, pid, wmic, tasklist

I'm trying to write a script that handles application deployment, based off new builds. Unfortunately, our software (java/weblogic) doesn't have a very reliable "shutdown" command, so we're more or less forced to just kill the running processes before deploying the new code to the environment location.

What I would like to be able to do is write a script that can either (a) determine what PIDs exist for a specific directory, or (b) list all processes and parse the directories from that output.

So far, I've only made slight progress with (b), in that I can `wmic process list` and get everything in the world printed. Is there a way to narrow this list down? I searched but couldn't find flags that would allow me to request just the PIDs and directories they exist in. I could use the current output, since it looks like directories are printed everywhere, but this seems super inefficient.

Comment: What have you tried? You can start narrowing it down like: `wmic process GET ProcessId, Name` or `wmic process where Name='blah.exe' get ProcessId` That said - are you shuttind down stuff inside of weblogic? If so there are better ways

Comment: Yes, I am shutting down a weblogic environment completely.

Comment: I would highly recommend making a WLST call to shut down the servers instead: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13813/reference.htm#i1060147 http://dirknachbar.blogspot.com/2012/08/startup-or-shutdown-of-multiple.html

Comment: Did you tried to run WebLogic instance as a Windows Service? Take look into http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81b/adminguide/winservice.html because you can start and stop services very easily on Windows.